# Is there limit of 5,000 rasters stored in folder by ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, windows-7, esri-grid-format

I have a python script that creates batches of ~6,000 cost distance rasters. These rasters are intermediate data that will be summarized in another process. Output is stored in plain old folders. However, at output raster 5000, my python script stops with the error msg something like: 'forcible close by a remote host.'

If I redirect the output for files 5000+ to a new folder, all works as before. I'm not sure if it's a folder size limit, since I can add shapefiles or other folders to the output folder (already containing 5000 rasters) without issue. The error is repeatable with different output and different folder locations.

Has anyone had this issue before and does anyone know where to change the folder limit?

Comment: Which format do you use? Esri GRID has a [limit of 5000 floating point grids](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Esri_Grid_format/009t0000000w000000/).

Comment: @Jens thanks for that. So it looks like my workaround options are 1. using multiple folders for output 2. switching from GRID to something else (but these files will be input to raster calculator so I'm not sure if that's useful). Does a file gdb count as an INFO directory? Wonder if I can store rasters that way?

Comment: From my experience (with ArcGIS 9.x) GRID is the most stable format to work with Spatial Analyst. So personally I would prefer workaround 1. (As far as I know restrictions of GRID do not have negative effects on fGDB.)

Comment: @Jens - Since it seems you have answered the question, why don't you take what you put in your comment and write it as an official Answer.  This way, it becomes searchable by other users who may be having the same problem.  Cheers!

Comment: You don't want to put 5000+ files into a folder, anyway: it degrades all accesses to datasets within or beneath that folder. Any time you have to create thousands (or even hundreds) of intermediate rasters for an analysis--which is an enormous amount of computing and I/O--you ought to rethink the algorithm: there's often a (much) better way. Consider posting another question in which you describe what you are trying to accomplish with this analysis and ask whether there might be efficient solutions that avoid creating all these intermediate results.

Comment: This may be a red herring as I have never used them but what about netcdf format as a storage mechanism?

Comment: @whuber my plan is to export the bazillion files to R and work with the data as a matrix. perhaps the best thing to do would be to create an in_memory cost distance raster and then use arcpy.RasterToASCII_conversion(inRaster, outASCII) for the hard copy output? http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/SDMTools/asc2dataframe.html

Comment: @Hornbydd in my limited experience with netcdf, i've always had to convert each layer to a grid in order to use it in calculations (in ArcGIS).

Comment: When you find yourself creating so many intermediate rasters you should always step back and ask whether that's necessary at all: often there's a different algorithm to achieve what you want that avoids so much computation. Also, unless your rasters are extremely small or your machine extraordinarily capable, you will not fit 5000 rasters into memory simultaneously using `R` or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use GRID raster format: There is maximum number of grid datasets that can be stored in a single workspace directory:

- Fewer than 5,000 floating point grids, or
- Fewer than 3,333 integer grids, with VATs, or
- Fewer than 5,000 integer grids, if no VATs), or
- Fewer than 10,000 grid stacks

More [details in ArcGIS help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Esri_Grid_format/009t0000000w000000/).